# Pass Iterable C++ class to Python using swig

Tags: c++, python, iterator, swig

I try to implement a C++ class which should be iterable. So far, I've written this:

```
class XYByFrameIterator {
 public:
  XYByFrameIterator(vector<xy>& precalc) :_precalc(precalc), _current(precalc.begin()), _end(precalc.end()) {}

  XYByFrameIterator* __iter__() { cout << "__iter__" << endl; return this;}

  xy& next() throw (Stop_Iteration) {
    if (_current == _end)
      throw Stop_Iteration();
    xy& ret = *_current;
    _current++;
    return ret; 
  }

 private:
  vector<xy>& _precalc;
  vector<xy>::iterator _current;
  vector<xy>::iterator _end;
};
```

To transform my custom C++ `Stop_Iteration` exception into a Python `StopIteration` exception I added this to the swig interface file:

```
%typemap(throws) Stop_Iteration %{
  PyErr_SetNone(PyExc_StopIteration);
  SWIG_fail;
%}
```

But unfortunately this works only in some cases. For exapmle, the following python code prints the x/y values as expected.

```
it = fa.xyByFrameIterator(43)
for xy in it:
    print(xy.x)
    print(xy.y)
```

But if I instantiate the iterator in the loop directly it crashes:

```
for xy in fa.xyByFrameIterator(43):
    print(xy.x)
    print(xy.y)
```

output:

```
__iter__
44.2233009338
5.83165979385
segmentation fault
```

**Update:**

I found a solution after reading this [answer](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.swig/9949). I assume there was something wrong with the `__iter__` method after passing it through to Python. Now I insert the `__iter__` directly in the Python code via the swig interface file. It now looks like this:

```
%typemap(throws) Stop_Iteration %{
  PyErr_SetNone(PyExc_StopIteration);
  SWIG_fail;
%}
%extend XYByFrameIterator
{
%insert("python") %{
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
%}
}
```

And my c++ code:

```
class XYByFrameIterator {
 public:
  XYByFrameIterator(vector<xy>& precalc) :_precalc(precalc), _current(precalc.begin()), _end(precalc.end()) {}
  xy& next() throw (Stop_Iteration) {
    if (_current == _end)
      throw Stop_Iteration();
    xy& ret = *_current;
    _current++;
    return ret; 
  }

 private:
  vector<xy>& _precalc;
  vector<xy>::iterator _current;
  vector<xy>::iterator _end;
};
```

This work quiet well, but I would prefer a solution with no (or less) code for each iterator class in the swig interface file.

Comment: Is this just a thin wrapper around an iterator pair from `std::vector`? There's easier ways to expose this via SWIG than what you've done if that's the case

Comment: In this example yes, but some values will not be cached in a vector.